# Prevent user from submitting finish button when a value of a drop down list is not selected

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to ask how to prevent the user from submitting the form if the value of a drop down list is not selected. I want a prompt something like "Please select from a drop down list". below is my jquery and html code.

```
    <div class="form-group" id="COPPRooms">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">COPP:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <select class="form-control" id='COPPMeetingRoom'>    
                                  <option value="1">COPP Board Room</option>
                                  <option value="2">COPP Training Room</option>
                                  <option value="Others">Others</option>


                            </div>
                        </div>

if($("#COPPMeetingRoom").val()=='0' && $("#NOPFMeetingRoom").val()=='0' && $("#MOPBMeetingRoom").val()=='0' && $("#NOPBMeetingRoom").val()=='0' && $("#LOPPMeetingRoom").val()=='0'){


     }
     else{
```

Comment: Please let me know you submitting form by the submit button or on change event of this select?

Comment: Yes I have a submit button after selecting from a dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:
with **option:selected** you can get the current selected option in your drop down menu and then compare it to what ever you like.

```
if($("#COPPMeetingRoom option:selected").val() == "0" ){
   promt code...
   alert("Please select...");
   or open a popup...
}
else{
   your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the select will have the first option selected when you submit a form , so you need to create a default option that will equal to the select beeing empty

```
<select class="form-control" id='COPPMeetingRoom'> 
   <option value="-1">Chose Room</option>
   <option value="1">COPP Board Room</option>
   <option value="2">COPP Training Room</option>
   <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
if($('#COPPMeetingRoom option:checked').val() == -1) {
 alert('chose a room from the select');

}
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/b5vdvbbj/

Comment: I mean, after applying what you have suggested and tried, I'm still not prompted with the alert.

Comment: No error, the data still saves, yes there is a button inside the form that says submit. <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Reserve</button>
                </div>
              </div>

Comment: are you preventing the default submit?

Comment: HI madalin ivascu thank you for your help.I'm still not getting my desired output.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: to prevent the user from submitting the form when he forgot to select the value from the drop down list.

Comment: did you see my jsfiddle demo ?

Answer (score 0):

when you are submitting form by submit button there you should check for the value of this select

in the form tag add this on submit attribute as: `<form onsubmit="selectValueCheck()">`

add this function containing code:

`if ($("#COPPMeetingRoom option:selected").val() == "0" ) {
     alert("Please select...");
     return false
  }
  else {
    return true
  }`

the value false will not let the form to be submitted